Handbrake not fully working
I recently got this 2013 Hybrid Hyundai, and my house has slanted parking so my brother-in-law helped me test if the handbrake works well. I put it in N while the handbrake is on and it still doesn’t fully hold. I want to know how to fix it or how much it would be to fix it for I won’t get scammed.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Is this a manual lever operated or an electronic emergency brake? Also, what's the model? Just saying hybrid doesn't say exactly what you have.
